# Cancel timer in onResume()?

Tags: android, timer, onresume

Is it possible to cancel a countdown timer in the `onResume()` method ?

For example: when the back button is pressed the `onResume()` method is called. I want to cancel the timer when it is in the login activity, in case of any other activity I want the timer to continue running.

I have thought about writing an `if()` condition in the `onResume()` activity and cancelling the timer but the timer does not stop.

My approach could be wrong, so please guide me.

```
void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(currentActivity.equals("LoginActivity")){
        timer.cancel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441145/onpause-onresume-activity-issues) question. It's not the exact same, but is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the countdown timer whenever the back button is pressed in the login activity. For that use the following code in your login activity.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //stop the timer
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { Log.v (TAG,"keydown"); if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) { timer.cancel(); } return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); } does not work :(..am i going wrong some whre

Answer (score 0):

If you use **TimerTask** then cancel TimerTask.

```
mTimerTask.cancel();
```

else cancel timer.

```
mTimer.cancel();
mTimer.purge();
```

I think this code may help you.

Comment: sry but i have to use countdown timer only :( according to the requirement